# Objective C UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a little issue here. Why does my search bar search when I start inputting some text? Here's the code:

```
     - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
         [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
         self.theTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
         self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
         [theTableView setRowHeight:110];
     }

     - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
         [tableView setRowHeight:[[self theTableView] rowHeight]];
         tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
         [self.tableData removeAllObjects];
     }

     - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
         searchBar.text=@"";

         [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
         [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
         self.theTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
         self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
     }

     - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

       // all the function to search

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:` and return NO. This should prevent the autoreloading of the data while you search.

Comment: What about if I do want table to reload, say after getting new data from the net. What would I do?